# Why to own an array if I don't want the ownership of objects it contains?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

I am creating an outletCollection of the buttons(present inside my view) in my controller. Since view already has a strong reference to the buttons it contains. On creating this collection Xcode added this code
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;`

Note the strong keyword in above.
My questions are :

**a) Why this code will break if use weak instead of strong ?**

**b) Do the ownership of array will give me the ownership of objects it contains ?**

*My thoughts on this :*
An array is just a collection of pointers(in this case). Since the parts of heap pointed by those pointers are already owned by view, That's it I can't follow any further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Why this code will break if use weak instead of strong

Because in case of collection, `IB` create instance of `NSArray` and place all references in it. You want to keep that instance of the array (note, not to objects in it, there are already strong references to them exist), because there's no more references to it. If you don't own the array - no one own and it will be released instantly. You can try to replace `NSArray` with [NSPointerArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) - it does not have strong references to objects within, for example.

So yes, it will break your code.

> b) Do the ownership of array will give me the ownership of objects it
>   contains ?

Yes, there's already exist collections that does not keep references, I think it just old template and in near future Apple will use them. ([NSPointerArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) for example), because current best practice is to have `strong` reference to top-most view (`self.view`) and `weak` to any of its subviews

Answer (score 2):

It is the array that is being defined with a strong reference. If you make `cardButtons` weak, then there won't be any other reference to the array and the array will get deallocated.

The buttons will still exist since their parent view still has a reference to them.

Since you need something to keep a reference to the array, its property is defined as strong.

Whether the array is strong, weak, or assign has no effect on the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The UIButtons are **singularly** retained by the view, but the NSArray is not. So if you don't retain the NSArray, you can surely access the buttons when you want (for example as subviews of the view), but you can't access them via the array.

And yes, the array by default gives you ownership on the elements.

Answer (score 2):

A) The reference to the collection array must be strong because the view does not reference the array itself. Only the class you are attaching the collection to has a reference to it so it must be a strong reference. If it were weak, the elements of the array would still be in memory, but the array itself would get deallocated.

B) An NSArray always has ownership over the contents of its array unless you use `-[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:]`

Comment: Pedant attack! You could use `CFArrayCreate` with suitable `CFArrayCallBacks` to create a non-retaining `NSArray` (since they're toll-free bridged). But it'd be `unsafe_unretained` in effect, not `weak`, so unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks! for the advice. For now i will use strong with NSArray in my code instead of using anything else.